# How to know if socket server is working

Tags: c, sockets

I am creating a socket server using c, but the client will be an arduino board so i would like to know if there is a way to be testing my code without the client since the arduino is yet to arrive.

Answer (score 2):

`telnet host port`.  Obviously use whatever port you are listening on, and you can always use 127.0.0.1 for your own address.